# Unix. Iterate through many subdirs with same structure. Find checksums file and compare file integrity

Tags: unix

I have a directory dirA with many subdirs named PER followed by a 3-digit integer (e.g. PER001, PER144, etc). Each subdir has a single subdir named after a random string, each of which has several files with they respective .sha256 files. Using unix, I want to search within dirA, compare each file with its respective .sha256 file, and output a text message with "Integrity of $fileX is good" if the checksum is good, and "Integrity of $fileX is bad" if the checksum is bad. This is what I did so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the main directory
dirA="/path/to/dirA"

# Find all .sha256 files and compare checksums
find "$dirA" -type f -name "*.sha256" -execdir sh -c '
    while read -r stored_checksum filename; do
        calculated_checksum=$(sha256sum "$filename" | awk "{print \$1}")
        if [ "$stored_checksum" == "$calculated_checksum" ]; then
            echo "$filename integrity is good"
        else
            echo "$filename integrity is bad"
        fi
    done < "$stored_checksum"
' \;
```

However, I get: "sh: line 8: : No such file or directory"

Comment: Usually, the variable used for input rediection (`done < "$stored_checksum"`) is a different value than the variable used to read input in the `while` loop body. Did you want `... done < "$checksum_list_file"` or something more like that? I'm surprised (a little bit) that shellcheck.net didn't flag this as at least a **warning**. Use `set -vx ; code with problems ; set +vx` to see code output a) as written (blocks, then lines), b) follow by lines prepended with `+` that show the actual command that is executed with all variable and cmd-substitions performed. ....

Comment: All dbl-quoted strings are "normalized" to a single quoted form. See `set -vx; echo "my String" ; set +vx` to see what I mean (as the most simple example). Good luck.

Comment: How do you populate `$stored_checksum`? What is its content?